# Upgrading old code to newer MySQL version

Tags: php, mysql, database, updates

I'm very much an amatuer at this kind of thing, but I am trying to teach myself about PHP and MySQL databases.

I'm trying to build my own local copy of the lesson talked about here: https://www.dougv.com/2009/03/27/getting-all-zip-codes-in-a-given-radius-from-a-known-point-zip-code-via-php-and-mysql/

I can get it to almost work, but I think the reason it isn't working properly is because it was written in 2009 in a now out-dated version of MySQL.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to updating this code?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{5}$/', $_POST['zipcode'])) {
      echo "<strong>You did not enter a properly formatted ZIP Code.</strong> Please  try again.\n";
 }
 elseif(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,3}$/', $_POST['distance'])) {
      echo "<strong>You did not enter a properly formatted distance.</strong> Please try again.\n";
 }
 else {
      //connect to db server; select database
      $link = mysql_connect('host_name', 'user_name', 'password') or die('Cannot connect to database server');
      mysql_select_db('database_name') or die('Cannot select database');

      //query for coordinates of provided ZIP Code
      if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM php_zip_code_distance WHERE zip_code = '$_POST[zipcode]'")) {
           echo "<strong>There was a database error attempting to retrieve your ZIP Code.</strong> Please try again.\n";
      }
      else {
           if(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
                echo "<strong>No database match for provided ZIP Code.</strong> Please enter a new ZIP Code.\n";
           }
           else {
                //if found, set variables
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
                $lat1 = $row['latitude'];
                $lon1 = $row['longitude'];
                $d = $_POST['distance'];
                //earth's radius in miles
                $r = 3959;

                //compute max and min latitudes / longitudes for search square
                $latN = rad2deg(asin(sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos($d / $r) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad(0))));
                $latS = rad2deg(asin(sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos($d / $r) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad(180))));
                $lonE = rad2deg(deg2rad($lon1) + atan2(sin(deg2rad(90)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad($lat1)), cos($d / $r) - sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($latN))));
                $lonW = rad2deg(deg2rad($lon1) + atan2(sin(deg2rad(270)) * sin($d / $r) * cos(deg2rad($lat1)), cos($d / $r) - sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($latN))));

                //display information about starting point
                //provide max and min latitudes / longitudes
                echo "<table class="\"bordered\"" cellspacing="\"0\"">\n";
                echo "<tbody><tr><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Lat</th><th>Lon</th><th>Max Lat (N)</th><th>Min Lat (S)</th><th>Max Lon (E)</th><th>Min Lon (W)</th></tr>\n";
                echo "<tr><td>$row[city]</td><td>$row[state]</td><td>$lat1</td><td>$lon1</td><td>$latN</td><td>$latS</td><td>$lonE</td><td>$lonW</td></tr>\n";
                echo "</tbody></table>\n\n";

                //find all coordinates within the search square's area
                //exclude the starting point and any empty city values
                $query = "SELECT * FROM php_zip_code_distance WHERE (latitude <= $latN AND latitude >= $latS AND longitude <= $lonE AND longitude >= $lonW) AND (latitude != $lat1 AND longitude != $lon1) AND city != '' ORDER BY state, city, latitude, longitude";
                if(!$rs = mysql_query($query)) {
                     echo "<strong>There was an error selecting nearby ZIP Codes from the database.</strong>\n";
                }
                elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
                     echo "<strong>No nearby ZIP Codes located within the distance specified.</strong> Please try a different distance.\n";
                }
                else {
                     //output all matches to screen
                     echo "<table class="\"bordered\"" cellspacing="\"0\"">\n";
                     echo "<tbody><tr><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>ZIP Code</th><th>Latitude</th><th>Longitude</th><th>Miles, Point A To B</th></tr>\n";
                     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                          echo "<tr><td>$row[city]</td><td>$row[state]</td><td>$row[zip_code]</td><td>$row[latitude]</td><td>$row[longitude]</td><td>";
                          echo acos(sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($row['latitude'])) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($row['latitude'])) * cos(deg2rad($row['longitude']) - deg2rad($lon1))) * $r;
                          echo "</td></tr>\n";
                     }
                     echo "</tbody></table>\n\n";
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I should have mentioned, I changed the "There was an error selecting nearby ZIP Codes from the database." message to `echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . " | $query</p>\n";` and I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND longitude != ) AND city != '' ORDER BY state, city, latitude, longitude' at line 1 | SELECT * FROM zipcodedistance WHERE (latitude <= 0.144722858078 AND latitude >= -0.144722858078 AND longitude <= 0.144722858078 AND longitude >= -0.144722858078) AND (latitude != AND longitude != ) AND city != '' ORDER BY state, city, latitude, longitude

Comment: What specific error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Change all instances of `mysql_` to `mysqli_`, then your DB connection too. [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) works differently; it requires DB connection for functions; query etc. and it comes first. Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), it's safer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks - I changed all the mysql_ to mysqli_ earlier, but obviously that didn't work on its own. what exactly do you mean by "then your DB connection too"? Again, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your edit *"EDIT: I should have mentioned, I changed the "There was an error selecting nearby ZIP Codes from the database." message to `echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . " | $query</p>\n";` and I get the following error:"* - Maybe `echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . " || $query</p>\n";`? Missing a `|` pipe character.

Comment: I see syntax error in `echo "<table class="\"bordered\"" cellspacing="\"0\"">\n";` which should be `echo "<table class=\"bordered\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";` that's one, so far.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I guess the error isn't really important. That is the error I get when I run the script, but I think the real reason is because I'm trying to run a depreciated code. That is what I want to fix.

Comment: Consult my [`first comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560377/upgrading-old-code-to-newer-mysql-version#comment39915281_25560377) then.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Thanks, I appreciate your help. I don't understand what you meant by "then your DB connection too" though? Cheers

Comment: Everything from A to Z must be `mysqli_` functions, it cannot contain any of the old `mysql_` functions, both those APIs do not mix together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fred -ii- is right.  All mysql_* needs to be change to mysqli_*.

That aside looks like you could run into a problem with this SQL statment.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM php_zip_code_distance 
        WHERE (latitude <= $latN AND latitude >= $latS AND longitude <= $lonE AND longitude >= $lonW)  
            AND (latitude != $lat1 AND longitude != $lon1) 
            AND city != '' 
    ORDER BY state, city, latitude, longitude
```

If `$lat1` or `$lon1` are empty your SQL will fail.  Try changing it to:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `php_zip_code_distance` 
        WHERE (`latitude` <= $latN AND `latitude` >= $latS 
                AND `longitude` <= $lonE AND `longitude` >= $lonW)  
            AND (`latitude` != '$lat1' AND `longitude` != '$lon1') 
            AND `city` != '' 
    ORDER BY `state`, `city`, `latitude`, `longitude`
```

(I prefer to wrap my field names in ``)

That way, if `$lat1` or `$lon1` are empty you won't end up with

```
AND (latitude !=  AND longitude != )
```

You'll end up with

```
AND (`latitude` != '' AND `longitude` != '')
```